# (Error: Custom pin not found) when trying to fill map with markers from hardcoded locations

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

I want to fill the map with hard coded coordinates to display the pin markers with custom map using Xamarin.Forms.Maps

My HardcodeLocations class is:

```
public class HardcodedLocations
{
    public static List<Position> Positions = new List<Position>
    {
           new Position(41.19197,   25.33719 ),
           new Position(41.26352,   25.1471 ),
           new Position(41.26365,   25.24215 ),
           new Position(41.26369,   25.33719 ),
           new Position(41.26365,   25.43224 ),
     };
}
```

In the constructor class I trying to load the markers like that:

```
public AboutPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int i = 0; i < HardcodedLocations.Positions.Count; i++)
    {
        CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = HardcodedLocations.Positions[i],
            Label = "Xamarin San Francisco Office",
            Address = "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA",
            Name = "Xamarin",
            Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
        };
        customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };
        customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
        customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(42.8742, 25.3187), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
    }
}
```

but I receive error here in CustomMapRender class in iOS project:

```
var customPin = GetCustomPin(annotation as MKPointAnnotation);
if (customPin == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
}
```

This is all code in the GetViewForAnnotation method in the same class:

```
protected override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
{
    MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;

    if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
        return null;

    var customPin = GetCustomPin(annotation as MKPointAnnotation);
    if (customPin == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
    }

    annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(customPin.Name);
    if (annotationView == null)
    {
        annotationView = new CustomMKAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.Name);
        annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("pin.png");
        annotationView.CalloutOffset = new CGPoint(0, 0);
        annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("monkey.png"));
        annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
        ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Name = customPin.Name;
        ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Url = customPin.Url;
    }
    annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;

    return annotationView;
}
```

I don't know how to fix this error because when I use basic xamarin.forms.maps (without customizing) I just fill the map like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < HardcodedLocations.Positions.Count; i++)
{
    Pin pin = new Pin
    {
        //Label = $"{i + 1}",
        Label = $"{i + 1}",
        Address = "Кликни тук за да видиш прогнозата.",
        Type = PinType.Place,
        Position = HardcodedLocations.Positions[i]
    };

    map.Pins.Add(pin);
}
```

This is the method of `GetCustomPin`:

```
CustomPin GetCustomPin(MKPointAnnotation annotation)
    {
        var position = new Position(annotation.Coordinate.Latitude, annotation.Coordinate.Longitude);
        foreach (var pin in customPins)
        {
            if (pin.Position == position)
            {
                return pin;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the `CustomPin` code:

```
    public class CustomPin : Pin
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

To change the pin, the entire code had to be refactoring with creating `CustomMap` and `CustomPin` classes in the basic project and creating `CustomMapRenderer` and `CustomMKAnnotationView` classes in iOS and Android project.

Reference: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/CustomRenderers/Map

Is there a way to clear this error?

## ===================================
UPDATE

In this method I trying to compare two Position properties like that:

```
CustomPin GetCustomPin(MKPointAnnotation annotation)
    {

        var position = new Position(annotation.Coordinate.Latitude, annotation.Coordinate.Longitude);

        foreach (var pin in customPins)
        {
            if (pin.Position.Latitude == position.Latitude && pin.Position.Longitude == position.Longitude)
            {
                return pin;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But I still receive the same error ;(

Comment: First, why is this line `customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };` **inside** of your loop?  This will **reset** the `CustomPins` collection on **every iteration** of the loop.  Second, if the problem is occurring because `GetCustomPin` is returning null, wouldn't it make sense to post the code for that method?

Comment: When I move customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin }; outside the loop I receive error: The name 'pin' does not exist in the current context

Comment: you **create** the `List` **before** the loop starts, and **Add** the pin to the `List` **inside** the loop

Comment: This has nothing to do with the map itself, but rather your logic of adding items to the map itself.

Comment: Like that I receive the same error in the same line ..

Comment: Code for CustomPin, and GetCustomPin is missing, without that we cannot help.

Comment: I think this is the CustomPin code and GetCustomPin method ?

Comment: your `GetCustomPin` will only work if the Lat/Long values match **exactly**.  Have you tried debugging this code to see why they are not matching?

Comment: you might need to compare the Lat/Long values individually instead of the two Position objects

Comment: When I stop debugger on foreach I see my customPins count=0 ?

Comment: OK, then backtrace and figure out why that is.  This is what debugging is - finding a problem in your code, and the tracking it to the source

Comment: Ok, I use if statement to compore two Posiotion object like that - pin.Position.Latitude == position.Latitude && pin.Position.Longitude == position.Longitude but I still receive the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason points out in the comments you need to change how you add items to the map.

```
List<CustomPin> pins = new List<CustomPin>();
for (int i = 0; i < HardcodedLocations.Positions.Count; i++)
{
    CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
    {
        Type = PinType.Place,
        Position = HardcodedLocations.Positions[i],
        Label = "Xamarin San Francisco Office",
        Address = "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA",
        Name = "Xamarin",
        Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
    };
    
    customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
}

customMap.CustomPins = pins;
customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(42.8742, 25.3187), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
```

You were overwriting CustomPins with a new list with a single item every iteration of your loop.

Comment: I trying your method but I still receive the same error in the same line..

Comment: This is the only code we can provide with your partial question.